# How to position site name and title over image

Tags: html, css

I want to place site title and tagline over the image in the header. I have created a fiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/rabmalin/tp84y/.

Height of image and site branding need to supporting responsive feature, so cannot not have fixed height. Also, it needs to work if only site branding is displayed and no image in the container. When I use position absolute, nav bar is going behind the image.

```
<div id="container">
    <header role="banner" class="site-header" id="masthead">
        <div class="header-image-wrapper">
            <img width="1140" height="152" alt="" src="http://nilambar.com.np/blue-planet/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cropped-Desert.jpg" id="bs-header-image">
            <div class="site-branding">
                <div class="site-info">
                    <h1 class="site-title">
                        <a rel="home" href="http://nilambar.com.np/blue-planet/">Blue Planet</a>
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="site-description">Demo of Blue Planet</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="blueplanet-nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul class="nav-menu" id="menu-top"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-4" id="menu-item-4"><a href="http://nilambar.com.np/blue-planet/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24" id="menu-item-24"><a href="http://nilambar.com.np/blue-planet/pages/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
        </ul></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: What about setting the image as the background for the element that you're using for the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `position: absolute;`, then you can look into the [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) CSS property. You can set different "heights" off of the page (it's a third axis). This way, you'll first be able to get the navbar to show over everything else.

Here's some sample CSS:

```
nav {
    //whatever else you want to have here
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
header img {
    //whatever else you want
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

The `z-index` of the header is 9, which is less than that of the `nav`, meaning it will be placed on top of the image when the page is rendered.

If this doesn't work, I'd try setting the background for your header as the image.

Comment: I need `nav` below the `header` and site title over the banner image. Can you check the fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.header-image-wrapper img {
position: relative;
}
.site-info {
position: absolute;
}
```

the containing div or img have to be relative and what you want on top is absolute. If it get's behind the img use z-index. :D

Comment: I tried similar but when I used absolute position header tag is not pushing down content below it. Below content is also starting from the starting of header. Can you check the fiddle please?